# Magento 2.2.5 upgrade to 2.4

Tags: magento-2.2.5, magento-upgrade, magento2.4

Quick question. Does anyone know if I can upgrade my Magento 2.2.5 straight into 2.4, or do I have to first upgrade to 2.3.x? I know there are some packages that 2.3.x needs that I have to install as well, but assuming I have all the dependencies and other requirements in check, will there be any issues from jumping from 2.2 to 2.4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your dependencies are perfectly checked, there could not be any issue for latest version, be confirm your php version which could support magento2.4. Remember to protect your application and db with the backup.

Answer (score 0):

Also check for missing PHP extensions, which occur during the **setup:upgrade** command, its starts with **rtrim()** or something like that.
I think version 2.4.x will still have version 2.3.x packages if they are not deprecated or removed.